# Cannot write to OpenCV frame captured by a different thread

Tags: c++, opencv

By using the following code, I can successfully capture and return frame from a separate thread to main(). But now I cannot write to the frame/cv::Mat (contour in main()) for display. If I do not use separate thread to for webcam then I can successfully write to the frame/cv::Mat. What am I doing wrong?

```
VideoCapture cap(0);    
class Camera 
{
    public:
        Camera(void);
        ~Camera(void);
        Mat captureVideo(void);
        
    private:
        Mat frame;
        double dWidth;
        double dHeight;
        double fps;
            
};
Camera::Camera(void) {
    int isrunning = 0;
    usleep(10);
    if (!cap.open(2))
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video camera.\n" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        isrunning = 1;
    }
    if(isrunning == 0) {
        this->~Camera();
    }  

    cap >> frame;        
}
Camera::~Camera(void)  {
    cap.release();  
}
Mat Camera::captureVideo(void) {
    cap >> frame;           
    return frame;
}

Camera cam1;
const int frameBuffer = 20; // Frame buffer
std::vector<cv::Mat> frameStack;    
int stopSig = 0; // Global stop signal...

void grabFrame(void) {
    Mat frame;
    
    ::frameStack.clear();

    while(!::stopSig) {
        frame = ::cam1.captureVideo();
        
        // 1. Remove one frame from the back, if the stack has more then 2 frames...
        if(::frameStack.size() > 2) {       //If the framestack has more then 2 frames...
            ::frameStack.pop_back();
        } 

        // 2. Add a frame at the front of the stack if the stack is not full...
        if (::frameStack.size() < ::frameBuffer) { 
            ::frameStack.push_back(frame);  // Put new frame on stack on the computer's RAM...
        } else {
            ::frameStack.clear();
        }
        
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat fr, outImg;                 // Captured single frames...
    Mat contour;                // Video stream showin countours of objects...

    ::frameStack.clear();
    thread t1(grabFrame);

    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow", 1);
    
    while(1) {
        if(::frameStack.size() >= 2)  {
            contour = ::frameStack.back();

            circle(contour, Point(150,150),50, Scalar(0,255,255),cv::FILLED, 8);// PROBLEM -> NO EFFECT
            putText(contour, "some text", Point(100,100), FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, Scalar(0,143,143), 2);// PROBLEM -> NO EFFECT

            imshow("Contour Video", contour);
        }
        
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) 
        {
            ::stopSig = 1;      // Signal to threads to end their run...
            frameStack.clear();
            break; 
        }
    }
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are sharing `stopSig`, `frameStack` and `frameBuffer` variables between the two threads.

When you are using shared memory between threads, you have to properly **synchronize** the access to that shared memory. One of the reasons why synchronization is needed is to prevent two threads modifying a variable at the same time. Another reason is *visibility* - a write to a variable by one thread can be cached inside the CPU cache, and a thread running on another CPU core won't see the variable change.

Perhaps the easiest way to synchronize memory access between threads is by using `std::mutex`. I'm not gonna post the whole code here, but you can read about mutexes in C++ online, for example, [here](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/03/cp11-concurrency-tutorial-part-2-protect-shared-data.html).